# GCP PubSub ordering does not order messages

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I’m trying to use the GCP pubsub ordering feature with node js. I’m sending a couple of messages with the same ordering key and after the first message gets acknowledged I’m receiving all other messages in the bunch but not in the order. You can see that behavior on the screen. Take a look at the timestamps. Why does this happen? As far as I understand I should only get another message after acknowledging the previous one.
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpcpw.jpg)

Code for publishing message:

```
const main = async () => {
  const pubSubClient = new PubSub()

  const keys = ['a', 'a', 'a']
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    console.log(chalk.green(`Sending message ${i + 1}, ordering key - ${keys[i]}`))
    await pubSubClient
      .topic('test-topic', { messageOrdering: true })
      .publishMessage({
        orderingKey: keys[i],
        data: Buffer.from(`Msg ${i + 1}`)
      })
  }
}
```

Code for pulling messages:

```
const main = async () => {
  const pubSubClient = new PubSub()

  const handleMsg = async (message: Message) => {
    const dataStr = Buffer.from((message.data as unknown) as string, 'base64').toString('utf-8')

    console.log(chalk.green(`Got message ${dataStr}, orderingKey - ${message.orderingKey}, ${new Date().toISOString()}`))
    // some processing happens here
    await sleep(10000)

    console.log(chalk.yellow(`Message ack ${dataStr}, orderingKey - ${message.orderingKey}, ${new Date().toISOString()}`))
    message.ack()
  }

  const subscription = pubSubClient.subscription('test-subscription')

  subscription.on('message', handleMsg)

  console.log('started listening...')
}
```

Comment: The messages arrived in order of the **orderingKey**. Also, your question does not have code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JohnHanley apologies, just added some code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process works well. There is no issue or problem.

You program is a subscriber connected to a PubSub subscription. A subscription can have multiple subscriber. So, PubSub send a first message to one subscriber (the only one in your case, but PubSub isn't aware of that).

The first message is well acknowledge on that "subscriber", PubSub choose to deliver the others. To optimize the network, PubSub deliver the message in bulk to the client (that's why you have the same timestamp). However, the messages are processed in order in your program; the PubSub client library ensure that order.

At the end of the day, you receive all the messages and process them in order. Job Done.

Comment: That makes sense now. Many thanks. Initially I thought that I will not receive the next message until I acknowledge the previous one. By any chance do you know whether it is possible to implement this flow with PubSub?

Comment: Do you mean to receive the next message only when the current one is ack? To prevent to receive message in bulk and to accept to have more network traffic & latency?

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: I never tested, but you can try to play with the [flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#flow_control). However, it's not "per orderingKey" it's global to the subscriber, and that add latency for ALL messages.